# How to get all product image with its sku using Rest API in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api

Using this api `/rest/V1/products/?searchCriteria=[]`

> I get all product details any option to get only product images with
>   sku

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can use filters to specify which fields you wish to return.

eg.

```
GET http://<host>/rest/default/V1/products/24-MB01?fields=sku,price,name

{
  "sku": "24-MB01"
  "name": "Joust Duffle Bag"
  "price": 24.99
}
```

To use with search criteria for list methods:

```
GET http://<host>/rest/V1/products/?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_gear&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=86&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=finset&fields=items[sku,name]
```

Source: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/retrieve-filtered-responses.html

If you mean 'return only skus which have images' then that is a different story...